# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: submit is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit

I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

I have multiple dynamically generated forms on the same page, with different ids and data-form-id attributes (#form-1, #form-2 etc.) but only one submit button on top of the page. On input i assign the respective data-form-id value to the submit button, and when i click the submit button it should submit the form with the respective id.

All seems to work as planned, but in the end I get an error in the console saying: 
Uncaught TypeError: formToSubmit.submit is not a function.
Is the concatenation the problem?
All help is greatly appreciated!

```js
$('.inputs').on("input", function(){
 // get the data-form-id from this textarea
 var this_id = $(this).attr('data-form-id');
 // set the submit button's data-form-id attribute with the textarea's id
 $('#submitBtn').attr('data-form-id', this_id);
});
 
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
 var formTo = $(this).attr('data-form-id');
 formTo = "$('#" + formTo + "')";
 console.log(formTo);
 formTo.submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="submitBtn" data-form-id="" type="button" value="send">

 <form id="form-1" action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="info" cols="30" rows="10" data-form-id="form-1" class="inputs"></textarea>
 </form>
 
 <form id="form-2" action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="info" cols="30" rows="10" data-form-id="form-2" class="inputs"></textarea>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the " " on the line : `formTo = "$('#" + formTo + "')";` in `formTo = $('#' + formTo);` because you build a String object and not a Jquery one so you try to submit a string and throw an error

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.inputs').on("input", function(){
 // get the data-form-id from this textarea
 var this_id = $(this).attr('data-form-id');
 // set the submit button's data-form-id attribute with the textarea's id
 $('#submitBtn').attr('data-form-id', this_id);
});
 
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
 var formTo = $(this).attr('data-form-id');
 in formTo = $('#' + formTo);
 console.log(formTo);
 formTo.submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="submitBtn" data-form-id="" type="button" value="send">

 <form id="form-1" action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="info" cols="30" rows="10" data-form-id="form-1" class="inputs"></textarea>
 </form>
 
 <form id="form-2" action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="info" cols="30" rows="10" data-form-id="form-2" class="inputs"></textarea>
 </form>
```